# gcc is unable to create an executable file

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg cloned from [ffmpeg github](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) (with gpu support using CUDA) in my windows instance. I'm using msys2 mingw64 commandline to run the following command. The `configure` script is present in the root of the cloned ffmpeg codebase mentioned above.

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/c/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include --extra-ldflags=-L/c/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64
```

But I get the following error:

```
gcc is unable to create an executable file.
If gcc is a cross-compiler, use the --enable-cross-compile option.
Only do this if you know what cross compiling means.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.libera.chat.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

`config.log` file looks something like this(I have removed most of the unnecessary lines in between the logs):

```
# ./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags='-I/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include' --extra-ldflags='-L/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64'
ACLOCAL_PATH=/mingw64/share/aclocal:/usr/share/aclocal
ALLUSERSPROFILE='C:\ProgramData'
ALL_COMPONENTS='
    
    aac_adtstoasc_bsf
av1_frame_merge_bsf
.
.
.
.
gcc -I/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include -c -o /tmp/ffconf.b4kwCEqD/test.o /tmp/ffconf.b4kwCEqD/test.c
gcc.exe: warning: Files/NVIDIA: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc.exe: error: Files/NVIDIA: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: warning: GPU: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc.exe: error: GPU: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: warning: Computing: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc.exe: error: Computing: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: warning: Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc.exe: error: Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include: linker input file not found: No such file or directory
C compiler test failed.
```

It looks like it is unable to recognise the directory names with spaces included. I've tried escaping using `\` as well as with double quotes and single quotes too. I've tried the following commands, but the result is the same:

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I /c/"Program Files"/"NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit"/CUDA/v12.1/include --extra-ldflags=-L /c/"Program Files"/"NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit"/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64
```

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags="-I/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include" --extra-ldflags="-L/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64"
```

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags="-I'/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include'" --extra-ldflags="-L'/c/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64'"
```

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp --enable-nonfree --extra-cflags=-I/c/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/include --extra-ldflags=-L/c/Program\ Files/NVIDIA\ GPU\ Computing\ Toolkit/CUDA/v12.1/lib/x64
```

Comment: It seems like the `./configure` itself has a problem with filenames with white-space characters. Why not rename (or copy to a new name?) the directory with white spaces to underscores (`_`), and then pass the different directory name?

Comment: @L_R I can't rename the "Program Files" directory, right?

Comment: Then copy it somewhere else without any spaces in the path.